# Authenticatin for HERE RouteMatching API

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm trying to use HERE's RouteMatching API of JavaScript
Current full code is here: https://github.com/code4history/ShibeContour/blob/d7e56a7/here_mapmatcher.js

For authentication, I coded like this:

```
import properties from "properties"
import hmacSHA256 from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha256.js'
import Base64 from 'crypto-js/enc-base64.js'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import {promises as fs} from "node:fs"

const getProps = async () => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    properties.parse("./credentials.properties", {path: true},  function (error, data) {
      res(data)
    })
  })
}

const getToken = async (props) => {
  const nonce = `${performance.now()}`
  const timestamp = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)

  const parameters = [
    "grant_type=client_credentials",
    `oauth_consumer_key=${props["here.access.key.id"]}`,
    `oauth_nonce=${nonce}`,
    "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256",
    `oauth_timestamp=${timestamp}`,
    "oauth_version=1.0"
  ].join("&")
  const encoding_params = encodeURIComponent(parameters)
  const base_string = `POST&${encodeURIComponent(props["here.token.endpoint.url"])}&${encoding_params}`
  console.log(base_string)
  const signing_key = `${props["here.access.key.secret"]}&`

  const hmac_digest = encodeURIComponent(Base64.stringify(hmacSHA256(base_string, signing_key)))

  const headers = {
    "Authorization": `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="${props["here.access.key.id"]}",oauth_nonce="${nonce}",oauth_signature="${hmac_digest}",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="${timestamp}",oauth_version="1.0"`,
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
  const body = `grant_type=client_credentials`

  const response = await fetch(props["here.token.endpoint.url"], {
    method: 'post',
    body,
    headers
  })
  return response.json()
}
```

This works well, I got authentication token successfully.
Like this:

```
{
  access_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsImN0eSI6IkpXVCIsImlzcyI6IkhFUkUiLCJhaWQiOiJIZ0NSaFV4...',
  token_type: 'bearer',
  expires_in: 86399,
  scope: 'hrn:here:authorization::org...'
}
```

But even I used this access_token, route matching call causes authentication error.

Code is:

```
const main = async () => {
  const props = await getProps()

  const token_data = await getToken(props)

  const body = await fs.readFile("gps/8DD83AC3-8B5A-4108-9CC0-2B78CF9936EC.kml", {encoding: "UTF-8"})
  const headers = {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token_data.access_token}`,
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
  }

  const response = await fetch(`https://routematching.hereapi.com/v8/calculateroute.json?routeMatch=1&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&apiKey=${props["here.access.key.id"]}`, {
    method: 'post',
    body,
    headers
  })
  const respond = await response.json()
  console.log(respond)
}

main()
```

Error response was like this:

```
{
  error: 'Forbidden',
  error_description: 'These credentials do not authorize access'
}
```

What is wrong?
I can't imagine what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason

API URL is not match.
We can find many candidate urls,

```
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json
https://routematching.hereapi.com/v8/calculateroute.json
etc...
```

but true working url is only

```
https://routematching.hereapi.com/v8/match/routelinks
```

which we can find in this document.
https://platform.here.com/services/details/hrn:here:service::olp-here:route-matching-8/api-ref

Once I changed API endpoint to this correct one, it works well.